# vb2pygui: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PythonCardApp'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I installed vb2pygui and after going ahead and installing the secondary components in order to run it, eg simpleparse, and changing the couple of lines of code to import the right things, eg wxPython to wx. I thought i had made all the fixes necessary. However, i am getting an error regarding line 282.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = model.PythonCardApp(VB2PyIDE)
        app.MainLoop()
```

I get the following error:

```
 File "C:/Users/Raj Saha/Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages/vb2pygui/vb2pyGUI.pyw", line 282, in <module>
    app = model.PythonCardApp(VB2PyIDE)        
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PythonCardApp'
```

I chose not to put the entire 283 line code on here. Here is a github link,
[vb2pygui.pyw](https://github.com/rajibsaha11/vb2pygui/blob/6fe610166d72e8dd8ab5f8d0e5b11e27aaff6cd2/vb2pygui.pyw)

Will do if asked. I was wondering if i was the only one to incur this problem. I am using python 2.7, windows 10, 64 bit on all.

Comment: if your code is large, you needn't post it all, but please try to formulate an [m.c.v.e](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For instance show your import statements.

Comment: @PaulRooney - Thanks. I read over the link that you suggested, however its the second to last line that isnt working, so i decided to add a github link.

Comment: I'm guessign your code is based from [this](https://github.com/reingart/vb2py/blob/master/vb2pygui/vb2pyGUI.pyw) does it run? If not it's likely an installation problem.

Comment: yes it is based on it. i am using what i downloaded from the vb2py website, [http://vb2py.sourceforge.net/index.html]